# Import "tensorflow.math" could not be resolved

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter, pylance

I am using Jupyter Notebooks on VSCode to create a U-Net.
Here is a quick snippet of my code that generates the error:

```py
# PREPARE U-NET MODEL
from tensorflow.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.keras.backend import clear_session
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Add, BatchNormalization, Concatenate, Convolution2DTranspose, MaxPool2D, SeparableConv2D
from tensorflow.math import reduce_mean
```

With the new update, Pylance is now integrated into Jupyter notebooks. However, it gives me an error saying that `tensorflow.math` cannot be resolved. I obviously did not explicitly not install the math part in TensorFlow.

The specific error given is `Pylance(reportMissingImports)`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
from tensorflow._api.v2.math import reduce_mean
```